# Bittrex v3 API - INVALID SIGNATURE response

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, cryptography, cryptojs

I am trying to use the [Bittrex v3 beta API](https://bittrex.github.io/api/v3) and I keep getting:

`{'code': 'INVALID_SIGNATURE'}`

as a response.

I have tried it with Javascript and Python, so I am including both scripts - please let me know if you see anything wrong.

Python (first attempt):

```
#!/Users/eamonwhite/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/bin/python3.6
import requests
import time
import hashlib
from pprint import pprint
import json
import hmac
import base64
import codecs

# api-endpoint 
url = "https://api.bittrex.com/v3/orders/closed"

api_key = b'yyyyyyyyy'
secret = b'xxxxxxxxx'

api_timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
print(api_timestamp)

params = {'marketSymbol':'BTC-LOOM','pageSize': 200,'startDate': '2019-09-25T01:10:27.000','endDate': '2019-09-25T01:29:27.000'}

signature = hashlib.sha512(b'').hexdigest()

pre_sign = api_timestamp+url+'GET'+signature
print(pre_sign)

pre_sign_var = pre_sign.encode()
sig = hmac.new(secret, pre_sign_var, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
headers = {'Api-Key': api_key, 'Api-Timestamp': api_timestamp, 'Api-Content-Hash': signature, 'Api-Signature': sig}
# sending get request and saving the response as response object 
r = requests.get(url = url, params = params, headers = headers) 

# extracting data in json format 
data = r.json() 

pprint(data)
```

Javascript (second attempt - pulling straight from API docs):

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const url = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/orders/closed';
const data = {'marketSymbol':'BTC-LOOM','pageSize': 200,'startDate': '2019-09-25T01:10:27.000','endDate': '2019-09-25T01:29:27.000'};

var content_hash = CryptoJS.SHA512('').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

var api_timestamp = new Date().getTime();

var pre_sign_string = api_timestamp+url+'GET'+content_hash;
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(pre_sign_string, 'xxxxxxsecretxxxxx').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

const headers = {'Api-Key': 'zzzzz', 'Api-Timestamp': api_timestamp, 'Api-Content-Hash': content_hash, 'Api-Signature': signature, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

function obj_to_query(obj, base_url) {
    var parts = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            parts.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
        }
    }
    return base_url+"?" + parts.join('&');
}

async function getOrders(url = '', data = {}, headers = {}) {

  return fetch(url, {
          method: 'get',
          headers: headers,
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        return json
      });
}

var query_string = obj_to_query(data, url)

var r = getOrders(query_string, data, headers);

console.log(r);
```

The error I am getting back concerns the `Api-Signature` header, all of the other headers are correct or they would have thrown an error - I have output the string that I have before I sign it, and it looks exactly the same as in the documentation, so I feel like this must be a problem with the API because it is still in beta.

Please let me know if this is the case so I stop trying :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for sharing your python code. I made some changes and got it working sharing my code hope it helps someone else:

```
import requests
import time
import hashlib
from pprint import pprint
import json
import hmac
import base64
import codecs
import urllib.parse
from collections import Counter


def query(method, request, query):
   if query != '' and method == 'GET':
      url = "https://api.bittrex.com/v3/" + str(request) + str('?') + str(urllib.parse.urlencode(query))
   elif method == "DELETE":
      url = "https://api.bittrex.com/v3/" + str(request) + str('/') + str(query)
   else:
      url = "https://api.bittrex.com/v3/" + str(request)

   api_key = 'key'
   secret = 'secret'
   api_timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))

   if method == "POST":
      payload = json.dumps(query)
   else:
      payload = ''

   contentHash = hashlib.sha512(payload.encode()).hexdigest()
   pre_sign = api_timestamp+url+method+contentHash
   signature = hmac.new(secret.encode(), pre_sign.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
   headers = {'Api-Key': api_key, 'Api-Timestamp': api_timestamp, 'Api-Content-Hash': contentHash, 'Api-Signature': signature, 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

   if method == "POST":
      r = requests.post(url = url, data=json.dumps(query), headers = headers)
   elif method == "DELETE":
      r = requests.delete(url = url, headers = headers)
   else:
      r = requests.get(url = url, params = payload, headers = headers)

   data = r.json()
   return data

def getbalance():
    return query('GET', 'balances', '')

def getopenorders(market):
    return query('GET', 'orders/open', {'marketSymbol': market})

def buylimit(market, quantity, rate):
    return query('POST', 'orders', {'marketSymbol': market, 'direction': 'BUY', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'timeInForce': 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED', 'quantity': quantity, 'limit': rate})

def selllimit(market, quantity, rate):
    return query('POST', 'orders', {'marketSymbol': market, 'direction': 'SELL', 'type': 'LIMIT', 'timeInForce': 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED', 'quantity': quantity, 'limit': rate})

def getorderhistory(market):
    return query('GET', 'orders/closed', {'marketSymbol': market})

def cancel(uuid):
    return query('DELETE', 'orders', uuid)

#print (getbalance())
#print (getopenorders('XRP-USD'))
#print (buylimit('XRP-USD', '60', '0.10000000'))
#print (selllimit('XRP-USD', '100', '0.20000000'))
#print (getorderhistory('XRP-USD'))
#print (cancel('orderid-bla-bla-bla'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why you didn't get the upvotes...

Answer (score 0):

finally got it working not sure why but one thing i did was move my `url` out of the variable and included it in the return statement of the function that creates the encodedURI string..however, it always spits back the same data no matter what marketSymbol I use, and only a few trades come back...this is the output i get for /orders/closed everytime regardless of `marketSymbol`:

```
[ { id: '62b7764c-2c35-4588-b01b-15fbc2e6fc16',
    marketSymbol: 'BTC-USD',
    direction: 'SELL',
    type: 'LIMIT',
    quantity: '0.00733630',
    limit: '8315.81600000',
    timeInForce: 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    fillQuantity: '0.00733630',
    commission: '0.15251830',
    proceeds: '61.00732139',
    status: 'CLOSED',
    createdAt: '2019-09-25T16:03:53.09Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-09-25T16:03:53.09Z',
    closedAt: '2019-09-25T16:03:53.09Z' },
  { id: '21ca06f8-8e00-4d71-993c-3a7d53f57f1c',
    marketSymbol: 'BTC-USD',
    direction: 'BUY',
    type: 'LIMIT',
    quantity: '0.00733630',
    limit: '8334.93200000',
    timeInForce: 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    fillQuantity: '0.00733630',
    commission: '0.15286890',
    proceeds: '61.14756163',
    status: 'CLOSED',
    createdAt: '2019-09-25T15:56:55.57Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-09-25T15:57:02.92Z',
    closedAt: '2019-09-25T15:57:02.92Z' },
  { id: '59f2d104-1213-4634-bbd9-6dc8e7d6b91f',
    marketSymbol: 'BTC-USD',
    direction: 'SELL',
    type: 'LIMIT',
    quantity: '0.00744902',
    limit: '8250.00000000',
    timeInForce: 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    fillQuantity: '0.00744902',
    commission: '0.15363603',
    proceeds: '61.45441500',
    status: 'CLOSED',
    createdAt: '2019-09-24T19:43:20.76Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-09-24T19:43:21.09Z',
    closedAt: '2019-09-24T19:43:21.09Z' },
  { id: 'e39d4a85-c144-493b-98e1-99c91db5bdad',
    marketSymbol: 'BTC-USDT',
    direction: 'BUY',
    type: 'LIMIT',
    quantity: '0.00939489',
    limit: '10001.59789805',
    timeInForce: 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    fillQuantity: '0.00939489',
    commission: '0.23468751',
    proceeds: '93.87500532',
    status: 'CLOSED',
    createdAt: '2019-09-22T16:37:46.92Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-09-22T16:37:46.92Z',
    closedAt: '2019-09-22T16:37:46.92Z' },
  { id: '5dcc5a06-1eab-460f-b353-78263e9dac0b',
    marketSymbol: 'BTC-USDT',
    direction: 'SELL',
    type: 'LIMIT',
    quantity: '0.00953213',
    limit: '9907.07077638',
    timeInForce: 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    fillQuantity: '0.00953213',
    commission: '0.23608870',
    proceeds: '94.43548654',
    status: 'CLOSED',
    createdAt: '2019-09-22T03:21:51.15Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-09-22T03:29:40.98Z',
    closedAt: '2019-09-22T03:29:40.98Z' },
  { id: 'bdc95671-fee0-46fb-bb48-4fdf2cee7cae',
    marketSymbol: 'GRS-BTC',
    direction: 'SELL',
    type: 'LIMIT',
    quantity: '22.56987578',
    limit: '0.00002226',
    timeInForce: 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    fillQuantity: '22.56987578',
    commission: '0.00000125',
    proceeds: '0.00050263',
    status: 'CLOSED',
    createdAt: '2019-09-22T03:15:19.59Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-09-22T03:15:19.59Z',
    closedAt: '2019-09-22T03:15:19.59Z' },
  { id: '3528c223-d40d-41bc-866c-6c92f0a38195',
    marketSymbol: 'GRS-BTC',
    direction: 'BUY',
    type: 'LIMIT',
    quantity: '22.56987578',
    limit: '0.00002254',
    timeInForce: 'GOOD_TIL_CANCELLED',
    fillQuantity: '22.56987578',
    commission: '0.00000126',
    proceeds: '0.00050871',
    status: 'CLOSED',
    createdAt: '2019-09-22T02:55:56.84Z',
    updatedAt: '2019-09-22T03:07:04.18Z',
    closedAt: '2019-09-22T03:07:04.18Z' } ]
```

I am submitting a ticket with Bittrex